# Javascript or Jquery: Scroll to Fixed position div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, css-float

I want a html div which will scroll when user scroll down the page and it will get to fixed position when it's parent tag ends. For example:- See this link http://www.9gag.com/ they have alot to posts on one page. When we scroll one post and go to end of the first post, the title and share buttons become to fixed position and then the second post do the same and same for the next posts. Just exactly like that. How can we do this in Jquery or raw javascript or in css.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to try this plugin: http://labs.anthonygarand.com/sticky/ Sticky is a jQuery plugin that gives you the ability to
make any element on your page always stay visible by making the element to be floated when they has reached the limit.

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).scrollTop()` will give you the number of pixels scrolled down in the browser, `$('postcontainer').offset()` will give you the x,y positions of a post container.

So if you bind an event to `$(window).scroll()` or to the mousescroll, you can check if the postcontainer's `offset().top` is less than the `window.scrollTop`. If it is then you start moving the item down relative to the post container. When doing this you need to keep track of the post container's height and the moving element's height to make sure it doesn't go down past the bottom of the container.

So if `postcontainer.height - movingelement.position().top >= movingelement.height()` then you need to fix the position of the moving element. Do the opposite while scrolling back up.

Hopefully this will get you thinking and starting to kick out some code.

Comment: can you please provide me at least one example.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for your problem with a simple css property.

use `position:sticky` to follows the scroll.

Here is the article explained.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit

and old way of doing this [demo](http://jsbin.com/omanut/2)

with [sticky position demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html)